# Does thread safetyness prevent duplicity in ConcurrentBag?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
public static ConcurrentBag<MyClass> all = new ConcurrentBag<MyClass>();

public static void Load()
{
    all.Add("first");
    all.Add("second");
    all.Add("third");
    all.Add("fourth");

    foreach (MyClass item in all)
    {
        item.Load();
    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed that I will have the "first" item once in my collection (which is desired)?
Can I iterate like this or do I need to use Parallel.ForEach ?

Comment: You are not using multiple threads to add. So why would you expect contention in any case?

Comment: Sounds like you need to be using [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2) rather than `ConcurrentBag`.

Comment: @AdamG I run this code every X seconds using BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

Comment: Obviously you can't add a string to something expecting a MyClass instance, so I will presume that those strings represent MyClass objects. Does your real load method take these objects as arguments or is the set of objects supposed to be the same for each call and really you only need the first to arrive to populate it?

Comment: @AdamG You presume right. I don't take them as arguments because they are singletons. I just need to create a collection that contains all of them. That means I only need this code to execute once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT guaranteed that the elements are unique:

"Bags are useful for storing objects when ordering doesn't matter, and unlike sets, bags support duplicates."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#definition

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you want a singleton collection and that you seem to want it to load by the first call, I have created a solution using [Lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). Alternatively to a ConcurrentBag, you could use [ImmutableList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185%28v=vs.111%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string description)
    {
    }

    public void Load()
    {
    }
}

public class MyClassLoader
{
    public static Lazy<ConcurrentBag<MyClass>> allLazy = new Lazy<ConcurrentBag<MyClass>>(() =>
    {
        ConcurrentBag<MyClass> bag = new ConcurrentBag<MyClass>();
        bag.Add(new MyClass("first"));
        bag.Add(new MyClass("second"));
        bag.Add(new MyClass("third"));
        bag.Add(new MyClass("fourth"));
        foreach (MyClass item in bag)
        {
            item.Load();
        }

        return bag;
    }

    );
    public static void Load()
    {
        foreach (MyClass item in allLazy.Value)
        {
        // Do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```